# PostgreSQL: Modifying column data type from Character Varying to Double Precision

Tags: postgresql, data-conversion, double-precision

I am encountering some problems regarding the alteration of column data types -- specifically from character varying to double precision. The goal of this modification is so I can perform SUM and average on this column.

Another way I've been trying to do this is create a new column with double precision and update that column with the character varying column, but no luck so far. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What specific ALTER TABLE commands have you tried? What were the results (including error messages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have any illegal values in that column (i.e. values that cannot be converted to a number), the following should do it:

```
alter table some_table 
   alter column some_column type decimal(10,2) using some_column::decimal;
```

I used `decimal` because using `double` is almost always a bad choice as that is an *approximate* data type which does not guarantee that you get the same value back that you store in it. See this website for details: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: `decimal(10,2)` means that numbers in `some_column` will have a total count of `10` digits, where `2` of these are decimal places t(to the right of the dot).